# "An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function" when using a flash drive with Windows 8 inside VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

How do you fix the error "An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function" when using a flash drive with Windows 8 inside VirtualBox

[image]

Answer (score 14):

To fix the error, install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) into your host VirtualBox. Make sure you also have the Guest Additions installed on the guest.

You may need to enable the USB 2.0 controller from the VM settings under `Settings>Ports>USB`:

[image]

Comment: This helped! But do note that the virtual machine must be off to change the USB version.